# Why is my HttpPostedFileBase always empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, file-upload, asp.net-4.5

In my `Create` `View` I have

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, FormMethod.Post, enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div>
            <h2>New Task</h2>
            <ol style="list-style-type: none;">
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formlabel" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formlabel" })
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Description)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Deadline, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formlabel" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Deadline, htmlAttributes: new { id = "date-picker", type = "text", @class = "hasDatepicker" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Deadline)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RankID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formlabel" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("RankID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standselect" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RankID)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PriorityID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "formlabel" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("PriorityID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "standselect" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PriorityID)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="uploadFile">Files</label>
                    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile" />
                </li>
                <li style="margin: 20px 0 0 32px;">
                    <input type="submit" class="ghButton btn btn-navy" value="Create" />
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>
    }
```

In my `Controller` I have

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ETaskModel taskModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
        {
            var tasksServ = new TasksService();

            //var files = Request.Files;//files
            var upFiles = uploadFile;//up files

            //returning recently created task
            DataAccess.Task createdTask;
            tasksServ.Create(taskModel.Title, taskModel.RankID, SessionHelper.User.ID, taskModel.Deadline, taskModel.Description, taskModel.PriorityID,
                null,   //---------documents
                null,   //implementator users
                out createdTask);


            var generalServ = new General();
            ViewBag.RankID = new SelectList(generalServ.GetRanks(), "RankID", "RankValue", taskModel.RankID);
            ViewBag.PriorityID = new SelectList(generalServ.GetPriorities(), "PriorityID", "Name", taskModel.PriorityID);
            return View(taskModel);
        }
```

On submit I receive data in my `ETaskModel taskModel` object. but `HttpPostedFileBase files` is always empty. Also `Request.Files.Count` is always 0;

What's my problem. It possible to upload file(s) and receive `ETaskModel` data simultaneously?

P.S. **uploadFile** name of the file upload and controller method parameter are the same!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using wrong overloaded version on `BeginForm`

Instead

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl, enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because your parameter in your Action needs to be named `uploadFile` instead of `files` to match the `id` provided on the form. Then, the file that was selected will be available.

Comment: I changed it (just forgot to write correctly here - in stackoverflow) BUT IT STILL DOESN'T WORK

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `HttpPostedFileBase` to your model,

```
    public class ETaskModel 
    {
      public string Title {get; set;}
      public string Description{get; set;}
      .
      .
      public HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile {get; set;}
    }
```

and in your controller,

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ETaskModel taskModel)
        {
          .
          .
        }
```

Didnt check the code, but this might work, Hope this helps.